# MySQL odd and even auto-incremented IDs

Tags: php, mysql, database-design

I have two tables in `MySQL`. Both tables store exactly the same thing, only that one table stores data that is not final (will be later changed) and one table stores final data.

```
NotFinal Table
----------------------
ID ParentID  Value
1     2       0.5
2     2       0.3
```

.

```
Final Table
----------------------
ID ParentID  Value
1     1       0.5
2     2       0.3
3     2       0.4
```

Now, the thing is that I want to select the `ID` of all entires that have `ParentID = 2`, doesn't matter from which table. If I select from their join then I will get `1,2,2,3` in which case the `ID 2` is duplicate (ID 2 has ParentID 2 in both first and second table).

So, the actual problem is I **don't know from which table the ID came from**. To fix this problem I was thinking in Non-final table to only have `odd` IDs and in the final table to have only `even` IDs. Doing this will never result in conflicting IDs and I will always know which ID came from which table.

Can I set up MySQL auto-increment so that the IDs in the first table are odd and in the second one are even?

So the tables would look like this:

```
NotFinal Table
----------------------
ID ParentID  Value
1     2       0.5
3     2       0.3
```

.

```
Final Table
----------------------
ID ParentID  Value
2     1       0.5
4     2       0.3
6     2       0.4
```

Comment: No you cant and its a weird way of solving this challenge

Comment: Well, I could use a single table and add a column with `IsFinal` but the problem is the performance (I will have to also check IsFinal column at each update and the updates are pretty often)

Comment: @Cristy Why is performance an issue? Ridiculous.

Comment: @Cristy Have you think about using union?

Comment: @Strawberry Well, right now I use `insert on duplicate update` in the non-final table, so I don't do any checking and there are very few entries to check against (once an entry is final it will be moved to the final table). And those updates are done sometimes more than 10-15 times/second.

Comment: why not just select `id` from different tables separately?

Comment: @tning Yeah, this could be an idea. But I still have to distinguish between the tables when I have an `id`, so maybe select them separately and then manually mark the `id`s from one table (eg make them negative). This is possible but I don't think it's the best solution (I wanted a MySQL only solution for this so I don't have to write PHP to solve this).

Comment: I suppose you need to perform some logic to these `id` depending on which table they are from. why not just `select id from non_final`, perform some `no_final_table` logic, then `select id from final`, perform some `final_table` logic.

Comment: @tning What I have to do is select all the `ID`s and return them (in a set) to the browser. Then, when someone wants to get the value for an `ID` it will send that ID to the server and the server will select based on that `ID`.  But if the `ID` appears in both tables it doesn't know from which one to select. So if I returned `1,2,-1,-3,4`  I would know that `1,2,4` are from first table and `-1, -3` means `1,3` from the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use configuration options `auto_increment_increment` and `auto_increment_offset` as mentioned in the [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-master.html).

Their primary use is for replication, but as they can be changed also in each session, you can use them for your purpose. Just set them as you need before manipulating either of these 2 tables (change only the session variables, not global ones).

Answer (score 1):

> I don't know from which table the ID came from

You can add details into your result set independently for each table in your union select. e.g. add a column for `is_final`:

```
SELECT ID,ParentID,Value, true as `is_final` FROM `Final`
union
SELECT ID,ParentID,Value, false as `is_final` FROM `NotFinal`
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not have them both in the SAME table? Add an extra integer column named IS_FINAL which can be set to 1 or 0. Set it to 0 for non-final records and 1 for final records. This would be a much cleaner way of solving the problem.

Comment: Check my comment above :)

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: @Cristy it seems we both came to the same conclusion!